# How to start debugging ColdFusion in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, coldfusion, cfeclipse

I have installed Eclipse and Java 1.8 (latest one including JRE). I have also installed CFEclipse but when ever I try to run the web app to debug it. I get the following error:

[image: error]

The steps I have taken:

1. Installed JDK and JRE
2. Installed Eclipse
3. Installed CFEclipse
4. Installed Adobe ColdFusion Development Server
5. Opened Project in Eclipse and Pressed the debug icon

Comment: The title says "debugging" but the question says "run". Can you clarify? Exactly what steps did you take to "run the web app"?

Comment: Sorry for that, let me edit the question

Comment: Eclipse + CFEclipse alone does not support line debugging for CF (only java, etcetera).  For CF line debugging you need to use Adobe's CFBuilder and enable it in the CF Admin  https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/developing-applications/developing-cfml-applications/using-the-coldfusion-debugger/set-up-coldfusion-to-use-the-debugger.html